# How to resolve Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, service, provider

I am trying to inject a service into a component in my Angular app.
I am using version 7 of Angular.

Here is my dashboard.component:

```
import { ArtistService } from './artist.service';

export class AdminDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private _artistService: ArtistService) { }
}
```

Here is some of my artist.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
    export class ArtistService {
}
```

When I navigate to the dashboard component, this error is logged to the console:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise):
>
> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[AdminDashboardComponent -> ArtistService]:
>
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[AdminDashboardComponent -> ArtistService]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for ArtistService!

I've tried to resolve this by updating my service with this decorator:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```

But I still receive the same error. Can someone please point out what I need to change? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: have you add `ArtistService` on your `AppModule` file

Comment: `providedIn` should work, please create a stackblitz to help you what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either you need to provide your service in a module (AppModule for example) like below

```
@NgModule({
   // ... other codes 
   providers: [
      ArtistService
      // ... other codes
   ]
})
```

or as you mentioned using `providedIn` as below in your service

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
```